# reuse the same instances of Dialogs

Tags: android, memory, interface

I saw many threads with this tittle, but no one really speak about "reuse" of dialogs: discussion  is only pick how to organize code to fabricate dialogs in same place, but with different Contexts.

So, I would like to know: its good practice to create few singleton dialogs, and then just change theirs styles and contentViews?

Its better than call each time new Dialog? (speed, memory consumption)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never use anything as *Singleton* and/or *Static* which requires reference to Activity's **Context**. Otherwise it will lead you to serious memory leaks. The best approach is to make use of dialogs within your activity classes regardless of their quantity you want, because the memory consumed by such dialogs will be released when your activity is destroyed.

Comment: Its looks like truth. I think to use single application context for this pattern, but its not works, despite of user rapports which concern the older versions of android api.